# How to use FULL-TEXT SEARCH in H2 Database?

Tags: database, full-text-search, h2

Consider the following example

```
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS FT_INIT FOR "org.h2.fulltext.FullText.init";
CALL FT_INIT();
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST;
CREATE TABLE TEST(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(1, 'Hello World');
CALL FT_CREATE_INDEX('PUBLIC', 'TEST', NULL);
```

and i have executed the following query

```
SELECT * FROM FT_SEARCH('Hello', 0, 0);
```

But this query is returning **"PUBLIC"."TEST" WHERE "ID"=1** .

1. Do i have to again execute this `"PUBLIC"."TEST" WHERE "ID"=1` to get the record containing 'Hello' word ?
2. What is the query to search all records with 'ell' word in them from the FT_Search. such as like %ell% in H2 Native Full-Text Search

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Yes, each row in a query using `FT_SEARCH` represents a schema-table-row where one of the key words was found. The search is case insensitive, and the `text` parameter to `FT_SEARCH` may include more than one word. For example,

   ```
   DELETE FROM TEST;
   INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(1, 'Hello World');
   INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(2, 'Goodbye World');
   INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(3, 'Hello Goodbye');
   CALL FT_REINDEX();
   SELECT * FROM FT_SEARCH('hello goodbye', 0, 0);
   ```

   returns only row three:

   ```
   QUERY                           SCORE  
   "PUBLIC"."TEST" WHERE "ID"=3    1.0
   ```

   Also note that `FT_SEARCH_DATA` may be used to retrieve the data itself. For example,

   ```
   SELECT T.* FROM FT_SEARCH_DATA('hello', 0, 0) FT, TEST T
   WHERE FT.TABLE='TEST' AND T.ID=FT.KEYS[0];
   ```

   returns both rows containing the keyword:

   ```
   ID   NAME  
   1    Hello World
   3    Hello Goodbye
   ```
2. [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/features.html) supports [wildcard](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#What_wildcard_search_support_is_available_from_Lucene.3F) searches, although *leading* wildcards (e.g. *ell) tend to be expensive.

Comment: That's exactly what i want. Thank you.

Comment: again is there any way to index h2 database with lucene if any tell me.

Comment: [Using the Lucene Fulltext Search](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#fulltext) is very similar, you just need the Lucene libs in your classpath.

Answer (score 4):

> Do i have to again execute this "PUBLIC"."TEST" WHERE "ID"=1 to get the record containing 'Hello' word ?

Yes, except if you use a join as described by trashgod. The reason is: usually rows are much larger than just two words. For example, a row contains a CLOB with a document. If the result of the fulltext search would contain the data, then fulltext search would be much slower.

> What is the query to search all records with 'ell' word in them from the FT_Search. such as like %ell% in H2 Native Full-Text Search

The native fulltext search can't do that directly. The reason is: fulltext search only indexes whole words. (By the way: does Google support searches if you only know a part of a word? Apache Lucene does support it) Actually, for H2, there would be a way: first, search the words table (FT.WORDS) for matches, and then use a regular search.

Comment: Yes, Lucene supports [wildcard](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#What_wildcard_search_support_is_available_from_Lucene.3F); I fixed the the (previously) broken link in my answer. Good idea on searching `FT.WORDS` for partial matches.

Comment: Actually, because the regular full text search connects the search terms using AND, simply looking for results from FT.WORDS in a single query may not work. Suppose you want to search for `AB%`, an FT.WORDS query may return `ABCDE` and `ABXYZ` as word candidates. Now a regular full text search for `ABCDE ABXYZ` will return the intersection, most likely the empty set.
To use the FT.WORDS approach, you would need to first expand your `AB%` term and then call the full text search for each expansion. And if you have multiple search terms, you will have to search for *all combinations*.